# How to open and close material navigation drawer in react

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I followed this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zg0kjVl5b6Y) (Full code on [github](https://github.com/kriscfoster/material-ui-drawer-react-router/blob/master/src/App.js)) and implemented the material drawer. Now I can't close the drawer or open it with something like a function. How can I do it?
also the drawer is not swapping.
How I can access to Drawer object inside my webpage (DOM)? And change it's state such `open = false`.
Sorry for my questions I'm very new to react.

```
        <Drawer
                variant="temporary"
                anchor="right"
                open={true}
                >
                <List>
                    <ListItem>
                        first text
                    </ListItem>
                    <ListItem>
                        b
                    </ListItem>
                </List>
            </Drawer>
```

I want to have a menu icon on top right of my page and when the user clicks on it a [modal](https://material.io/components/navigation-drawer#modal-drawer) navigation drawer will display.

Comment: You have to use react state to and set open to `false` on click

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are many examples [here](https://material-ui.com/components/drawers/) in material-ui docs of how to use Drawers. check [this](https://material-ui.com/components/drawers/#temporary-drawer) out

Comment: Please include the relevant part of the links into your answer, otherwise, if the links ever die, your answer would become useless.